# Language Translation is not working?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, translation, multi-language, language

**My wpconfig.php file:**

```
define('WPLANG', 'tr_TR');
```

**My Code:**

```
echo '<div id="wtdCustomizButtonDetailsPage"><a href="'. $getCustomPage .'?type=wtd_sc_designer&wtd_id='. $id .'">'. __('Customize', 'wctd') .'</a></div>';
```

**My PO File Naming:**

[image]

**Inside of my PO File:**

[image]

What am I missing ? The text still is in English.

Comment: how do you load the MO file ? show us the code you use

Comment: @mmm what do you mean by loading mo file? Please tell me which page's code or sections code you want me to share with you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following function in your plugin:

```
load_plugin_textdomain ();
```

and be sure that the directory to languages folder is correct.

This fixed the issue for above question.